# Intercepting & modifying commands

Tags: command-line, user-commands

Is it possible to intercept incoming user commands? For example, if the user executes `:echo 'hello'`, then I would like to compare the string and the command, and change it to execute `:echoerr 'hello'` instead.

My goal at the end is to intercept commands to check for their uppercase alternative. Vim does not allow lowercase commands as to not conflict with native ones, so I want to intercept commands as they come by and run a check to determine which command to run. For example:

`!command Cmd !echo test`

If I were to run `cmd`, Vim would not recognise it as a command. What I want to do is to see if `Cmd` exists instead, and if so run that command. I would also like to prioritise native commands if there's a conflict.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to achieve as this may be an XY problem? [This gist by romainl](https://gist.github.com/romainl/56f0c28ef953ffc157f36cc495947ab3) on overloading `:grep` may be a starting point depending on your use case.

Comment: @AndrewHo-Lee Certainly. I updated my question.

Comment: `My goal at the end is to intercept commands to check for their uppercase alternative.` In other words, to overwrite a built-in command. This is forbidden.

Comment: What you can do is to play around `cnoremap / cnoreabbr`. Something that was already pointed by the link above.

Comment: I don't want to overwrite a built-in command. I want to redirect a nonexistent command somewhere else. The problem with `cnoreabbr` is that it abbreviates things I would otherwise not want.

Comment: Again, you are not allowed to do anything with builtins. Even if they do not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading between the lines of your question, I *think* what you want to do is to to be able to type user-defined commands in lower case.  If that is the case, as discussed in the comments, `cnoreabbrev` is one way of doing this.  Something like this may help you get started:

```
let c_all = getcompletion("*", "command")->filter({_, v -> v =~# "^[A-Z]"})
for c_orig in c_all
    let c_lower = tolower(c_orig)
    if ! exists(':' . c_lower)
        execute "cnoreabbrev <expr> " . c_lower . 
                    \ " (getcmdtype() ==# ':' && getcmdline() ==# '" . c_lower . "') ? '" 
                    \ . c_orig . "' : '" . c_lower . "'"
    endif
endfor
```